# @GuardedBy , @ThreadSafe ,@NotThreadSafe

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I see that the above annotations are used extensively in the book JCIP . I think it is really useful because even in the absence of proper documentation it says some things about the synchronization policies . I also see that [Intellij Idea](http://jetbrains.dzone.com/tips/concurrency-hot-try-jcip) makes use of these annotations Are they now actually part of the Java language itself ?

Comment: No it is not part of the standard JDK - you need to import a dependency.

Comment: On [jcip.net](http://jcip.net), the jar link in "Concurrency annotations: jar, javadoc, source" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: http://jcip.net/jcip-annotations.jar

Comment: thanks for this info. How can I accept a comment as an answer -:)? @assylias since you were the first to provide the link would you write something so that i can accept ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

These are custom annotations that are not part of the standard JDK. To be able to use them in your code, you need to add a dependency.

At [jcip.net](http://jcip.net), there is a link to the library and its source in the bottom part of the page "*Concurrency annotations: jar, javadoc, source*".

Direct links:

- [jar](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jcip-annotations.jar)
- [javadoc](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/annotations/doc/index.html)
- [source](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jcip-annotations-src.jar)

Comment: These were standardized in JSR-305 (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.0)

Comment: The project's status is dormant. Do you know if there's any chance that it will be included at some stage?

Comment: They may be bundled in JSR-308 which is still active. The jsr305 annotations were intended for documentation only, so they offer value even if the jsr is dorment.

Comment: I'm disappointed that these annotations aren't standard.  I won't include a library in my project just for documentation.  So I'll just include the guarding details in my javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependency from maven repository

> "Java Concurrency In Practice" Book Annotations » 1.0

[jcip-annotations-1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0)