# Why is this class threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading

[image]

Had there been a

```
 public synchronized void deletePerson(Person p)
      { mySet.remove();}
```

then too it would remain threadsafe?

Comment: `@ThreadSafe` is not part of the Java API. It must come with a third party library and you should look into the documentation for the same. You may look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362298/guardedby-threadsafe-notthreadsafe

Answer (score 5):

This class is threadsafe because there is only one mutable field in it (`mySet`) , it is `private` and all accesses to it are *synchronized*.

Yes, `public synchronized void deletePerson(Person p) { mySet.delete();}` would still keep this class *thread-safe*.

Also, note that the reference to `mySet` is not escaping from this class. Which is also important.

Comment: suppose there are two threads thread1 and thread2. thread1 gets the lock on mySet object ,adds Person P1 through addPerson() method releases the lock. Due to some unlucky timing it might happen that thread2 gets the lock on mySet object, removes the Person P1 and releases the lock. Then thread1 will then get a false value from containsPerson().

Comment: @prvn - No. it can't happen. *Synchronization* enforces a *happens-before* relationship. So, it is guaranteed that before a lock is acquired, a thread sees all the changes made by other threads

Comment: yes, exactly thread2 sees that thread1 added P1 , it then removes P1, thread1 sees the changes made and therefore when it calls containsPerson() , it gets a false value. But this scenario is not we call as threadsafe. If a thread adds a info it should retrieve the same info that it added. But here its not happening.

Comment: @prvn - No. *thread-safe* means - get the *latest* state and NOT - *what thread changed* state

Answer (score 0):

Since `mySet` is private and not exposed outside the class through a `getMySet` method, you can access to the state of the object only with the methods `addPerson`, `containsPerson` and `deletePerson`.

Since these 3 methods are synchronized, only one of them can access to the instance of the class (and change its state) at any given time, so the class is Thread Safe.