# Does @GuardedBy("mutex") make data thread safe or is it just a documentation

Tags: java, multithreading

I have noticed people use  **@GuardedBy("mutex")    private Map map = new HashMap()**
Does this make the map thread safe? I doubt. How can this code decide what kind of thread safe map to use?
I guess it is just a kind of documentation.

Comment: It's just documentation, explaining what _field_ will be used to guard access to the `map`. Are you reading the concurrency book? This should be explained at the beginning of the book.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362298/guardedby-threadsafe-notthreadsafe

Comment: sure m reading.. just had an argument with someone over the same. As you can see, I can't believe it really makes something thread safe. The mechanism is not specified at all.

Answer (score 5):

It is documentation. A static analysis program could examine your Java class file, which includes the `@GuardedBy` annotation, and report that not all reads or writes were guarded by the lock. The [SpotBugs program does so](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#is-field-not-guarded-against-concurrent-access-is-field-not-guarded)

Answer (score 4):

By default, `@GuardedBy` is not handled in any specific way, and that's fine. Annotations are metadata that often documents intent.

Adding specific annotation handling to the language is something that could negatively affect the readability and the simplicity of the code, so it needs to be done with care.

- There are cases where an actual behavior being embedded in the annotation is fine (e.g. `@Override`)

If you take a look at what are the intended usages for annotations, though (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/), you can easily imagine some ways that you can take advantage of `@GuardedBy`.

IIRC, FindBugs was the first tool that handled the JCIP annotations, and you can easily imagine that in a specific project you can implement tooling that actually makes annotated collections thread-safe (given some constraints that should be fine with your project).

I think the main point of `@GuardedBy` is the mental model, that almost always you want to keep a track of which resources are guarded by which locks. It's not a bad habit to imagine "what should this shared data be guarded by" each time you share something between threads.